SMPlayer 24.5 on Ubuntu 24.04 does not play video files from external drive. Ubuntu 24.04 difficulties like Bluetooth, Nautilus, TaskBar
After installing Ubuntu 24.04 (same on Xubuntu), there was a problem with SMPlayer version 24.5. I get an MPV error when I want to run a movie from an external drive. The SMPlayer 23.12 version installed via Synaptic Package Manager does not have such a problem, unfortunately there is no 24.5 version there (on MPS).
Moreover, SMPlayer on Ubuntu 24.04, whether higher or lower, has a very uncomfortable setting of the window size. You have to discover (or even invent) that you right-click on the main SMPlayer panel and turn on "resize". (In Xubuntu 22.04 you had to hover over the corner of the window and click and hold and move - more convenient). In SMPlayer 23.12 you can only go in one direction, because to make it in two directions you have to jump exactly into the diagonal movement, which is quite difficult. In SMPlayer 24.5, surprisingly, it is a bit better - moving to the right immediately enables resizing in two directions (diagonally).
I successfully used the above command in the terminal:
sudo snap connect smplayer:removable-media

From the site:
videos from non-linux partition don't play
The MPV error stopped and running the movie from the Dolphin Manager became possible. However, running the movie directly from SMPlayer 24.5 is no longer possible because there is no /media path, and there is no way to force it manually. The setting in SMPlayer next to Interface "Use system file selection window" does not work either. I don't have this Permissions option in Snap (Software Center). Anyway, it's better, but it could be even better if it could be run directly from SMPlayer.
By the way, after removing Nautilus (now called Files), the Desktop as a directory stopped working. I had to install through the ubuntu-desktop terminal to get it back.
I haven't had such miracles since I've been using Linux for 20 years.
I regret a bit that I switched from Xubuntu to Ubuntu because in order to set the clock (increase the digits and change the date layout) on the top TaskBar and remove the Unity sidebar, I had to download three widgets through the Extension Manager, but before I discovered the Extension Manager it took me 4 days of struggling with this system and reading the Internet. Moreover, we still had to find a way to display it continuously on the Bluetooth bar, and after installing the Bluetooth Manager it still gives an error, but it works.
Is it possible to improve SMPlayer?
P.S. 20240523 11:12
SMPlayer can see the /media manager from its own window, but it only does it on the second try. After turning SMPlayer off and on again and entering the Directory, it stops seeing /media, only after the second entry to the Directory the visibility of /media is activated.
